# Splitting data into new columns

Tags: dataframe, columnsorting

I was wondering if anyone could advise me on a problem I am having with 'r'.

I am working on a drug trial of sorts, with data from 3 experimental conditions.

For every participant, six data points were collected. Meaning each participant is represented on one row, with 6 columns of data points.

However I am now trying to create a 3 level longitudinal model, but in order to do so I need to reformat my data so that instead of each participant having one row with 6 columns, there will be 6 rows for one participant, with two columns, one indicating the round of data collection (1-6), and the other giving the actual value.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I am hoping I won't be stuck manually reformatting my data, as it will cost me a lot of time that I'd rather invest into analysing the results.

I will also need to combine all three data frames into one main data frame to run the model, but I assume this will be an easy step once I figure out the first problem.

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: See [pandas.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) & [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: Hi Trenton! Thank you for the response. I apologise for the poor phrasing. Can I edit the question to include the troubleshooting that I have been doing or should I create a new question?

Comment: [edit] the question. Be sure to add code and a sample of the data